# How do you give su the current user environment variables

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a variable that is set through `.bashrc`.

In `~/.bashrc`:

```
PROJ_HOME=~/Projects/stable
```

From a bash shell, I'd like to do something like this:

```
$ su -l kenneth -c 'echo $PROJ_HOME'
```

However, when I do this, the expected `/home/kenneth/Projects/stable` is not printed out.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to export the variable. You may not need to use the `-m` option to `su` to preserve the environment.

```
export PROJ_HOME=~/Projects/stable
```

Comment: Assuming the export does change to root's env vars. Does `su -m` preserve ROOT's env? or kenneth's?

Comment: @8None1: According to the man page: "Preserve the current environment...". So that means the environment of the user calling `su` (presumably kenneth's - root isn't involved based on any information in the question).

Comment: The `~` gets expanded by the shell to the current user's home directory when you create this variable. If that's not what you actually want, this answer won't work.

Answer (score 21):

Have you tried the option su -m ?

```
-m, --preserve-environment
              do not reset environment variables
```

For example: su -m kenneth -c 'echo $PROJ_HOME'

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the answer but it appears that doesn't work. `$ su -m kenneth -c "echo $PROJ_PATH"`.

I get an empty line.

Comment: @kennethkoontz  `"echo $PROJ_PATH"` should have single quotes:  `'echo $PROJ_PATH'`, otherwise it'll get expanded before `su` and `echo` are invoked?

Answer (score 7):

Try with `su -m -l kenneth -c 'echo $PROJ_HOME'`. -m should preserve the environment.

EDIT
Reading your question one more time, I think I might understood it reversed.
You might also try this: `su -l kenneth -c '. /home/kenneth/.bashrc; echo $PROJ_HOME'`.

Comment: With the `-l` (for "login") flag, `su` won't preserve the environment. — What if you remove `-l`? From the docs (`man su`):  *"-m -p [...] If --login is not used, the environment is copied, except for the" ...* — note: if --login **not** used.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple steps here which you need to understand.

```
PROJ_HOME=~/Projects/stable
```

creates a variable *in the current shell* with the *expanded* value of the path. In other words, if you are logged in as user `luser`, the variable will contain something like `/home/luser/Projects/stable`.

If the intent is for `su` to get the value `/home/kenneth/Projects/stable` you either need to evaluate this expression as that user, or rewrite it to contain the expected value for `kenneth` before running `sudo`.

In the first instance, if the assignment is in a file `/etc/project.rc` you can simply

```
su -l kenneth -c '. /etc/project.rc; echo "$PROJECT_HOME"`
```

In the second case, maybe try something like

```
PROJECT_HOME=~kenneth/Projects/stable su -m -l kenneth -c 'echo "$PROJECT_HOME"'
```

though of course that unattractively hardcodes the value for Kenneth (and your shell might not actually have the facility to expand `~kenneth` to the home directory of `kenneth`, in which case maybe use [`getent`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getent.1.html) etc).

Answer (score -1):

I also fixed this issue and I fixed by exporting env variable into profile. Below is my sample code:

```
echo export runner_token=$(echo $resp_json | jq -r '.token') >> /etc/profile
su -p - ubuntu -c '$HOME/actions-runner/config.sh --url https://github.com/${gh_repo_user}/${gh_repo_name} --token "$runner_token"  --name MAC-AWS-RUNNER --labels ${gh_runner_labels}'
```

Answer (score -3):

Use single quotes around the command:

```
$ su -l kenneth -c 'echo $PROJ_PATH'
```

Double quotes interprets the value of `$PROJ_PATH` as seen by root (empty string), then executes the command `"echo (empty string)"` as the user kenneth.

Single quotes will pass `'echo $PROJ_PATH'` as the command, and the value of `$PROJ_PATH` in kenneth's environment is what will be echoed.

Comment: This is not horribly wrong, but the question already has single quotes around the command.